# Rails: Trying to get Bootstrap's offset class to work

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get these form fields centered using Bootstrap's offset class.

Attached is an image of my current form, and also what I want the form to look like. The offset class does not seem to be working for me.

Any help would be much appreciated!

All of the following code is within a div.container:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-6">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control'%><br /><br />
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control' %><br /><br />
    <%= f.label :image %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :image, class: 'form-control-file' %><br />
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I couldn't convert it to `erb`, however, have a look at [it](https://jsfiddle.net/nvxzgL39/) and make changes as needed.

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Can you please check if you are getting correct classes after rendering of erb. offset class you are using is from bootstrap4. Are you using right version?

Comment: @HDox I honestly don't know what version of Bootstrap. I'm a student and still learning.

My application.scss file has the following:

`@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";`

Comment: @PardeepDhingra see my above comment to HDox

Comment: @bax `<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">` try this?

Comment: @Gabbar Nope - it stayed on the left side, forms got shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Offsetting columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-offsetting)

In Bootstrap, for offset class name is `.col-md-offset-*`
so it should be

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  #...
</div>
```